# Z-fighting when drawing texture on both sides in iOS OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am simulating page flipping in iOS and I tried to draw different textures on both sides of a page. But I find out that the rendered page is thrashing even if I did not change any vertex or texCoords.

Below are the codes called in each frame:

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glCullFace(GL_BACK);

...

Shader2D* shader = [Shader2D getInstance];
glUseProgram(shader.shaderProgramID);
glVertexAttribPointer(shader.vertexHandle, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*)vertices);
glVertexAttribPointer(shader.textureCoordHandle, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*)texCoords);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(shader.vertexHandle);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(shader.textureCoordHandle);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, [[textures objectAtIndex: 0] textureID]);
glUniformMatrix4fv(shader.mvpMatrixHandle, 1, GL_FALSE, (const GLfloat*)&mvpMatrix);
glUniform1i(shader.texSampler2DHandle, 0);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, numIndices, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (const GLvoid*)page.frontFaces);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(shader.vertexHandle);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(shader.textureCoordHandle);

glUseProgram(shader.shaderProgramID);
glVertexAttribPointer(shader.vertexHandle, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*)vertices);
glVertexAttribPointer(shader.textureCoordHandle, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*)texCoords);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(shader.vertexHandle);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(shader.textureCoordHandle);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, [[textures objectAtIndex: 1] textureID]);
glUniformMatrix4fv(shader.mvpMatrixHandle, 1, GL_FALSE, (const GLfloat*)&mvpMatrix);
glUniform1i(shader.texSampler2DHandle, 0);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, numIndices, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (const GLvoid*)page.backFaces);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(shader.vertexHandle);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(shader.textureCoordHandle);

...


glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
```

It is worth mentioning that I use different indices winding order for both sides. `page.frontFaces` are defined counter-clockwise and `page.backFaces` are defined clockwise.

Here is my shader:

```
static const char* fragmentShader2d = MAKESTRING(
precision mediump float;
varying vec2 texCoord;

uniform sampler2D texSampler2D;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(texSampler2D, texCoord);
}
                                              );

static const char* vertexShader2d = MAKESTRING(
attribute vec4 vertexPosition;
attribute vec2 vertexTexCoord;

varying vec2 texCoord;

uniform mat4 modelViewProjectionMatrix;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = modelViewProjectionMatrix * vertexPosition;
    texCoord = vertexTexCoord;
}
                                              );
```

**SCREENSHOT**:

In my codes, the front side of the page is red with white characters and the back side is orange and black. As you can see from images, the back side of page was drawn irregularly near the right border of the front side. And apparently, at this time, only the front side of the page should be drawn.

It is worthy of noticing that in both images, the vertices and texCoords remain the same. As a matter of fact, the vertices and texCoords are constant in each frame but the rendered images are **NOT**! And I think it is related to depth buffer.

There are only **eight** triangles representing the mesh of a page. And it is good to ignore the video background.

[image]
[image]